# Showing a subset of $S_n$ is a subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

Let $P$ be the set of all the elements of $S_n$ which can be written as $\sigma\mu\sigma^{-1}\mu^{-1}$ for $\sigma, \mu \in S_n$. Show this is a subgroup.

This doesnt seem to be as simple as rearranging elements and manipulating terms. I'm quite stuck. Can anyone help?

I've tried rearranging $klk^{-1}l^{-1}mnm^{-1}n^{-1}$ to get in the form $\sigma\mu\sigma^{-1}\mu^{-1}$

Comment: What've you tried?Show your work by editing your post.

Comment: Rearranging elements and manipulating terms isn't working because the statement is false for an arbitrary group. To prove it for $S_n$, you'll have to apply some special knowledge about $S_n$.

Comment: @Learner- edited

Comment: @ChrisCulter I'm not claiming it for an arbitrary group- I'm claiming it for $S_n$ What special facts?

Comment: Hint: Can you think of a way of showing that $P$ is actually $A_n$, the alternating group on $n$ letters?

Comment: @BenS. This is from an exam question. It first asks me show to that any member of $A_n$ can be expressed as the product of 3 cycles. I did this. Then to show that any 3 cycle can be expressed in the form $\sigma\mu\sigma^{-1}\mu^{-1}$ .Done. I can see that $\sigma\mu\sigma^{-1}\mu^{-1}$ is always even, so $P \subseteq A_n$. I however cannot show that every **product** of 3-cycles can be expressed in this form. This is why I need $P$ to be subgroup. Then every product can. So any member of $A_n$ can. so $A_n \subseteq P$ and so $P=A_n$. Im stuck on the crucial part of showing the product.

Comment: @BenS. Are you thinking of a  way to show it's $A_n$ by avoiding this route? and then showing it's a subgroup?

Comment: @Arcane1729 That's exactly what I'm thinking of. I'll leave an answer below in order to explain a little better.

Comment: Is the question really about showing that the commutators form (not generate) a proper subgroup? This is basically the same as showing that every element of $A_n$ is a commutator, which is a bit long for an exam question -- a proof is e.g in Ore, *some remarks on commutators*, Proc.AMS 1951,      http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1951-002-02/S0002-9939-1951-0040298-4/

Comment: @ahulpke in the exam it was said to take it for granted that P was indeed a subgroup. But usually it asks to prove such statements- so I was curious and tried. If this is a difficult or long statement to prove then I guess that must be the reason.

Comment: @Arcane1729 Ah -- that explains it. The proof I cited is not hard per se, but is a somewhat lengthy case distinction. A more plausible exam question would be e.g. to show that every 3-cycle is a commutator.

Comment: @Arcane1729 To clarify, you're right, and I understand the claim. But *if* the generic strategy of just rearranging $klk^{-1}l^{-1}mnm^{-1}n^{-1}$ were to successfully prove the claim, then it would actually succeed in proving more: that the claim *is* true for arbitrary groups. Contrapositively, since we know the claim *is not* true for arbitrary groups, we know that the generic strategy can't possibly succeed. That tells use we need to bring in some facts that are specific to $S_n$, like its relationship with $A_n$ or the cycle decompositions of its elements.

Comment: @ChrisCulter understood

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the comments:

Let $(xyz)$ be a $3$-cycle in $S_n$. Then $(xyz)=(xzy)^2=((xy)(xz))^2=(xy)(xz)(xy)(xz)=(xy)(xz)(xy)^{-1}(xz)^{-1}$, so $(xyz)\in P$. We also know that the 3-cycles generate $A_n$. So, if we can show that a finite product of $3$-cycles can be written in the form $\sigma\mu\sigma^{-1}\mu^{-1}$, then we are done.

Comment: I can do it for a product of two disjoint -If you have $(a_1a_2a_3)(a_4a_5a_6)$ then you have $[(a_1a_3)(a_4a_6)][(a_1a_2)(a_4a_5)][a_4a_6)(a_1a_3)][(a_4a_6)(a_1a_2)]$ Can't do it for finite disjoint or two not disjoint and certainly not for finite not disjoint.  Hint please?